# inner div container centering issue within wrapper

Tags: html, css

Creating a gallery of divs with links images and text. problem is- can't get the inner wrapper to center everything.  `margin:0 auto;` isnt working because i havent set a width for it. but i want the width to change with different browser sizes but that the inner `.prjctwrap` divs will be centered within it. here's my markup:
HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="innerprjctwrap">
<div class="prjctwrap">
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<div class="imageCont" style="background-image:url(image1.jpg);">
</div>
<div class="text">Text Text Text</div> </a> </div>
...this reapeats from prjctwrap with other images, text and links
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:100%;
height:1000px;    }
.prjctwrap {
display:inline-block;
width: 130px;
height:180px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:15px;    }
.prjctwrap .imageCont{
width: 130px;
height: 100px;
background-size: cover; }
.prjctwrap .text {
text-align: center;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
height:80px; }
.prjctwrap a {
text-decoration:none;   }
#innerprjctwrap {
margin:0px auto;    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set any size on the `#innerprjctwrap` element, so it will have the default setting `width: auto;`. That means that it will use the full width available, so you can't see that it's actually centered.

Set a width on the element, and you will see that it is centered:

```
#innerprjctwrap {
  width: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want to use text alignment to center the content inside the element, you shouldn't use margins to center the element, you should use `text-align` to center what's inside it:

```
#innerprjctwrap {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: i want it to be as wide as the outer `#wrapper` so it changes with the sizing of the browser.. will edit my question to make this clear

Comment: @user3108832: Then you don't want to center the element, but centering what's inside it. I already added code for that option above.

Answer (score 1):

Add a width for `#innerprjctwrap` other ways `margin:0 auto;` not detected

**Eg:**

```
#innerprjctwrap {
margin:0px auto; 
width:200px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JsFiddle for explaining such problems will be much clear.
Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alansalexer/2C5NK/1/) what you want?

If so, then you want is actually to center elements inside #innerprjctwrap like @Guffa says, simply add:

```
#innerprjctwrap{
     text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add width. if no progress, try removing 'px'. if there's still no progress, use padding in the wrapper div.